# python cx_oracle module not working in PyCharm (with anaconda), but it does with command line

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, cx-oracle

I am trying to solve an issue with PyCharm that is literally driving me crazy. I hope I will get some help here.

I am running anaconda with python 3.5 on mac os. I need to use an oracle database and I have installed the cx_Oracle package using the official instructions with "pip install". 
I wrote a piece of code to test the connection with the database. If I run the code from the command line, it works fine, but PyCharm does not seem to like it. The GUI seems to not find the package, as there is a red line under the import saying "No module named cx_Oracle". But I can find the module listed with the other packages in  "Settings->Project->Project Interpreter". If I run it anyway, in PyCharm, I get the following error:

`import cx_Oracle
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myuser/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libclntsh.dylib.12.1
  Referenced from: /Users/myuser/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found`

The project interpreter is the same as the one I am using with the command line, I have checked that with the "which" command.

sys.executable, os.getcwd() and sys.pat, are all the same in both PyCharm and from command line.
The only difference seems to be in os.environ. In order to have the cx_Oracle plugin working from command line I had to set two environment variables DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If I don't set those I will get the same error with the command line too. Hence in PyCharm I have added the following lines at the beginning of my python script.

```
os.environ["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"]="/path/to/my/library"
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]="/path/to/my/library"
```

Unfortunately I still get the error if I run the code from PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

I fix similar problem by following cmd:

ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.dylib.12.1 /usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib.12.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to the location in which the Oracle client library (libclntsh) is found. Since PyCharm is loading it you need to make sure those environment variables are set prior to launching PyCharm itself, as they do not take effect *except* at process startup.

Another option is to set the environment variable FORCE_RPATH to some value prior to building cx_Oracle and installing it. This will remove the need for setting the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Anthony. Yes they are pointing to the right path, in fact if i don't use pycharm, and I launch the script from command line it does work.

Comment: I kind of solved the issue with an hack by adding DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the edit configuration -> environment variable, of every python script I need to run. But this is a very not elegant solution, as I have to do this for every script. It doesn't work if i set them in the main configuration settings.

Comment: can you suggest a better solution than the one I hacked in maybe?

Comment: Can you run PyCharm from the command line in which you know the variables are set correctly?

Comment: Find out the command that will start PyCharm and execute it from the shell after making sure that cx_Oracle works properly first.

Comment: I added another potential solution which may work better for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. But I see what you had in mind there.
Still same situation. It works from command line. And it works if I manually insert in every run configuration in pycharm the environment variable. But it doesn't without this tedious process.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. What Oracle client are you using? Instant client or full client? What version? If the run path is embedded in the library (using the FORCE_RPATH directive noted above) then it should work regardless of the setting of LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can use ldd to figure that out. If you have already installed the library you may have to deliberately destroy the build directory and rebuild in order for the setting to take effect.

Comment: I am using the instant client 12_1. What should I set the FORCE_RPATH directive to? which ldd should I use to figure that out? how? thanks.

Comment: The instant client should have the FORCE_RPATH set automatically but if not, any value at all will do. The general value is "1" though. The ldd command is one that will simply show the shared libraries that are going to be used for a particular executable or shared object and is useful for determining if your environment is correct. If you have FORCE_RPATH set during the build you don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH at all.